# Retrieve data from 3 tables where 1 table might not contain values and 'where' condition for 3rd table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch 3 tables data using left join..table names are tblOffer,tblCompanyDetails and tblFavourite.

```
SELECT tblOffer.OID, tblOffer.OfferCategory, 
    tblOffer.OfferTitle,tblOffer.OfferDetails, 
    tblOffer.ProductImagePath,
    tblOffer.IsExciting,
    tblOffer.ExpiringDate, 
    tblCompanyDetails . *,
    tblFavourite.IsFavourite 
FROM tblOffer 
    LEFT JOIN tblCompanyDetails ON tblOffer.CID = tblCompanyDetails.CID 
    LEFT JOIN tblFavourite ON tblOffer.OID = tblFavourite.OID 
WHERE tblOffer.OfferCategory = 'shopping'
```

there is no row exist in  tblFavourite. so tblFavourite.IsFavourite value is null.

I have one more condition to fetch data from tblFavourite.

```
SELECT tblOffer.OID, 
    tblOffer.OfferCategory, 
    tblOffer.OfferTitle, 
    tblOffer.OfferDetails, 
    tblOffer.ProductImagePath, 
    tblOffer.IsExciting,
    tblOffer.ExpiringDate, 
    tblCompanyDetails . *,
    tblFavourite.IsFavourite 
FROM tblOffer 
    LEFT JOIN tblCompanyDetails ON tblOffer.CID = tblCompanyDetails.CID 
    LEFT JOIN tblFavourite ON tblOffer.OID = tblFavourite.OID 
WHERE tblOffer.OfferCategory = 'shopping' 
    AND tblFavourite.UID = 1
```

please note the condition i wrote.. tblFavourite.UID = 1 at the end.i know that condition is wrong.

how can i get these three tables and tblFavourite.IsFavourite = 0 if no row exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing `tblFavourite.UID=1` in the `WHERE` clause, you have effectively transformed the `LEFT JOIN` on `tblFavourite` into an `INNER JOIN`. If you move that criteria into the `ON` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause, then you will still get rows form the primary table (`tblOffer`) even if there is no matching row in `tblFavourites`.

As for replacing `NULL` with `0` for `tblFavourite.IsFavourite`, you can do that with the `COALESCE()` function.

Something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT tblOffer.OID,
       tblOffer.OfferCategory,
       tblOffer.OfferTitle,
       tblOffer.OfferDetails,
       tblOffer.ProductImagePath,
       tblOffer.IsExciting,
       tblOffer.ExpiringDate,
       tblCompanyDetails.*,
       COALESCE(tblFavourite.IsFavourite,0)
FROM tblOffer
LEFT JOIN tblCompanyDetails ON tblOffer.CID = tblCompanyDetails.CID
LEFT JOIN tblFavourite ON tblOffer.OID=tblFavourite.OID AND tblFavourite.UID=1
WHERE tblOffer.OfferCategory='shopping'
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the condition on the optional data in the left join, so it will not filter out results if this condition is not met:

```
SELECT tblOffer.OID, 
tblOffer.OfferCategory, 
tblOffer.OfferTitle, 
tblOffer.OfferDetails, 
tblOffer.ProductImagePath, 
tblOffer.IsExciting,
tblOffer.ExpiringDate, 
tblCompanyDetails . *,
tblFavourite.IsFavourite 
FROM tblOffer 
LEFT JOIN tblCompanyDetails ON tblOffer.CID = tblCompanyDetails.CID 
LEFT JOIN tblFavourite on tblOffer.OID=tblFavourite.OID and tblFavourite.UID=1
where tblOffer.OfferCategory='shopping'
```

Comment: i want to return 0 if tblFavourite.IsFavourite have no values..yours is returning in null..but this also helped me to realize condition should be optional in left join.thank you